# How to plot the solutions to the following differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have the following set of differential equations:

\begin{align*}
\ddot{\theta}(s) & = \Gamma_{\varphi \varphi}^\theta\dot{\varphi}(s)^2 = \frac{\sin\theta \dot{\varphi}(s)^2}{(2+\cos\theta)},\\
\ddot{\varphi}(s) & = 2\Gamma_{\theta \varphi}^\varphi\dot{\varphi}(s)\dot{\theta}(s) = -\frac{2\sin \theta \dot{\varphi}(s)\dot{\theta}(s)}{(2+\cos\theta)}.
\end{align*}

where $s \in [0,1]$. How can I plot the solutions to this system?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

First you need initial/boundary conditions. After observing the odes, the last

one can be rearranged as

$$
\frac{\ddot{\varphi}(s)}{\dot{\varphi}(s)}=-\frac{2\sin \theta \dot{\theta}(s)}{(2+\cos\theta)}
$$

or

$$
\ln(\dot{\varphi}) = 2\ln(2+\cos(\theta))+C
$$

or

$$
\dot{\varphi}= C_0e^{2\ln(2+\cos(\theta))}
$$

etc.

```
sol = NDSolve[{theta''[s] == Sin[theta[s]] psi'[s]^2/(2 + Cos[theta[s]]), 
         psi''[s] == -2 Sin[theta[s]] psi'[s]/(2 + Cos[theta[s]]), 
         theta[0] == psi[0] == psi'[0] == 0, theta'[0] == 1}, {theta, psi}, {s, 0, 1}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[{theta[s], psi[s]} /. sol], {s, 0, 1}]
```

Note that with $\varphi(0)=\varphi'(0)=0$ we have $\varphi(s)=0$ so remains $\theta(s) = c_1 + c_2 s$

Comment: That was nice, I didn't notice! Unfortunately, substituting that $\dot{\varphi}$ in $\ddot{\theta} = C_0^2\sin\theta (2 + \cos\theta)^3$ doesn't yield something useful? For the initial conditions we can assume that $\theta(0) = \varphi(0) = 0$ and $\dot{\theta} = 1$ and $\dot{\varphi} = 0$. I guess this is possible?